# Using the select function on MySQL

Tags: mysql

For an homework, I need to have a query to shows the max value of `t.idEtape` which = `idEtape` for each `idEtape` while also showing the value of `nomEtape`, `Livrable` while also not using the group by function.

I've been trying for a while to figure this out and I'm about to give up. I have some like that at this time but this isnt working:

```
SELECT `idEtape`,`idProjet`,`nomEtape`, `Livrable`
FROM `jegere.EtapexProjet` , `jegere.Etape`
where `idEtape` = (select max(`t.idEtape`) from `jegere.EtapexProjet`)
```

Can anyone provide some enlightenment ?

Thanks

```
INSERT INTO `jegere.Etape` (`idEtape` , `nomEtape`, `Livrable`) VALUES
(1,'Démarrage','Définition du base de projet (objectifs, chef du projet)'),
(2,'Prébision','Planification du projet (périmètre, activités, ressources req)'),
(3,'Réalisation','Exécution du plan du projet'),
(4,'Surveillance et Maîtrise','Rapport de performance'),
(5,'Clôture','Document de clôture du projet');

INSERT INTO `jegere.EtapexProjet` (`t.idEtape`,`idProjet`, `dateDebut` , `dateFin`) VALUES
(1,1,'2011-07-01','2011-09-01'),
(2,1,'2011-09-02','2011-11-30'),
(3,1,'2011-12-01','2012-07-07'),
(4,1,'2012-07-08',NULL),
(1,2,'2012-05-01','2012-05-10'),
(2,2,'2012-05-11','2012-06-01'),
(3,2,'2012-06-02','2012-07-01'),
(4,2,'2012-07-01','2012-07-21'),
(5,2,'2012-07-22','2012-07-23'),
(1,3,'2011-11-01','2012-01-20'),
(2,3,'2012-01-21','2012-04-01'),
(3,3,'2012-04-02', NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Partial answer; and Lessons)

Lesson 1:

When fetching from two tables, do not use the old syntax:

```
FROM a, b
WHERE a.x = b.y  -- how the tables are related
```

Instead, use the new syntax

```
FROM a
JOIN b  ON a.x = b.y  -- how the tables are related
```

Lesson 2:

If you leave off the `a.x = b.y`, you have a `CROSS JOIN`, in which the query return all pairs of rows from the two tables.  (Cross join is *rarely* used.)

Lesson 3:

When JOINing tables, qualify *every* column so that the reader knows which table contains each column.  I like to use "aliases" to make the qualification less bulky:

```
SELECT p.`idEtape`, e.`idProjet`, e.`nomEtape`, '.`Livrable`
    FROM `jegere.EtapexProjet` AS p
    JOIN `jegere.Etape` AS e
      ON ...
    ...
```

Lesson 4:  When asking a question here, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can see the datatypes, indexes, etc.